# Insert Max Value of Column into Another Column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table defined by:

```
create table apple(

A number,

B number);
```

Now, I need to get values in the table such as the following:

```
A      B
------------------
1      4(max of A)
2      4(max of A)
3      4(max of A)
4      4(max of A)
```

How can I insert these rows, making `B` the maximum value of `A`?

Answer (score 5):

Welp, first you want to insert 1-4 into your table:

```
insert into apple (a) values (1)
insert into apple (a) values (2)
insert into apple (a) values (3)
insert into apple (a) values (4)
```

Next, you're going to want to update your table to set `b`:

```
update apple set b = (select max(a) from apple)
```

As you can see, it's a two-part process. You can't get the max of `a` until you've created that column!

Comment: +1 Exactly. This is not an INSERT process but rather an UPDATE process that happens on an already-inserted-to table :)

Answer (score 1):

And of course, if you're wanting to have a select statement to grab that other field, use the OVER clause:

```
SELECT a, MAX(a) OVER() as b
FROM table;
```

Edited:

And for an existing table you can do:

```
UPDATE t SET b = maxcnt
FROM (
    SELECT *, MAX(a) OVER() as maxcnt
    FROM table
   ) t;
```

(I think this works in Oracle... definitely fine in MS-SQL)

Rob

Answer (score 0):

Since 11g version you are able to use Virtual colums (their values calculated in real-time)
So that you should change your column definition as follows:

```
create table apple (
A number,
 B number GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( max(A) ) VIRTUAL 
);
```

I dont have Oracle 11g for testing, so cant check, but it should be working. 
Also you could use user-defined function for Virtual column.

See http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/VirtualColumns_11gR1.php for more examples and info!

Official docs for Create table in 11g:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_7002.htm